# Get accelerate package to log test results with huggingface Trainer

Tags: python, huggingface, wandb, accelerate

I am fine-tuning a T5 model on a specific dataset and my code looks like this:

```py
accelerator = Accelerator(log_with='wandb')
tokenizer = T5Tokenizer.from_pretrained('t5-base')
model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('t5-base')

accelerator.init_trackers(
project_name='myProject',
config={
# My configs
    }
)
# Then I do some preparations towards the fine-tuning

trainer_arguments = transformers.Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
# Here I pass many arguments
)
trainer = transformers.Seq2SeqTrainer(
# Here I pass the arguments along side other needed arguments
)

# THEN FINALLY I TRAIN, EVALUATE AND TEST LIKE SO:

trainer.train()
trainer.evaluate( #evaluation parameters# )
trainer.predict( #test arguments# )
```

Now my main issue, when I check the `wandb` site for my project, I only see logging for the `trainer.train()` phase but not the `trainer.evaluate()` or `trainer.predict()` phases.

I've scoured the web trying to find a solution but could not find any.

How do I get wandb/accelerate to log all of my phases?

Thanks!

For the full code, you can see it here:
https://github.com/zbambergerNLP/principled-pre-training/blob/master/fine_tune_t5.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Evaluation and Prediction metrics are not logged automatically  like they do for Training on `wandb`. But there are ways to push them on `wandb`.

##### Solution 01

You can log evaluation and prediction metrics manually, after each phases:

```
# After evaluation
eval_metrics = trainer.evaluate()
wandb.log({"evaluation": eval_metrics})

# After prediction
predictions = trainer.predict(test_dataset)
wandb.log({"predictions": predictions.metrics})
```

##### Solution 02

You can also set a callback that will log your metrics automatically, after evaluation and prediction:

```
from transformers import TrainerCallback

class WandbLoggingCallback(TrainerCallback):
    def on_evaluate(self, args, state, control, **kwargs):
        # Log evaluation metrics
        metrics = kwargs.get("metrics", {})
        wandb.log({"eval": metrics})

    def on_predict(self, args, state, control, **kwargs):
        # Log prediction metrics
        metrics = kwargs.get("metrics", {})
        wandb.log({"predictions": metrics})

# Use this callback in your trainer
trainer = transformers.Seq2SeqTrainer(
    # Your arguments
    callbacks=[WandbLoggingCallback],
    # Other needed arguments
)
```

Here's a [simple colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1kYKcKjzZ47bUQP0mXkSurQCrva5SiiHU?usp=sharing) that I borrowed from `HuggingFace` and modified it with ways to push evaluation and prediction metrics after training. You will find both manual and automatics approach there.